# Error "DrawerLayout" 2018

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo un problema con esto, el "DrawerLayout", mira

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi build.gradle (Módulo: aplicación)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema indica que no existe el estilo especificado:

> Failed to find style 'navigationViewStyle' in current theme

Tienes que agregar el tema dentro de `Styles.xml`

```
<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
     <!-- menu item text size-->
     <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
     <!-- menu item height-->
     <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item>
</style>
```

y llamarlo, supongo que es usado por tu `NavigationView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       ...
       ...    
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
       ...
       ...
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Hola @JorJorgesys♦, al parecer el problema que tenia era mi "appcompat", la versión ahora es "'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'" y el support design es "com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1". Ya con eso cargo con éxito, igual gracias por la ayuda...